# How to construct a SOCP problem and solve using cvxpy and cvxpylayers

Tags: portfolio, cvxpy, convex-optimization, cvxopt

I'm trying to solve a SOCP problem using `cvxpy` and integrating it to `cvxpylayers`. I'm looking at [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6861535) SOCP problem (**problem 11**) ([here](https://sci-hub.se/https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6861535) is the scihub link in case you can't access), and here is a snippet of the problem (note `min (p-t)` comes from an adaptation of *problem 4* using *expression 8* in the link above):

[image]

Go to ---> **EDIT 2**

**OLD**

I've looked at [this](https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/socp.html) example, but is still stuck and can't get the problem to be solved. Here is a sample code at my attempt:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

N = 5

Q_sqrt = cp.Parameter((N, N))
x = cp.Variable(N)

z = []
zero = []
for n in range(N):
    z.append((Q_sqrt @ x)[n])
    zero.append(cp.Constant(0))
    
p = cp.sqrt(cp.sum_squares(Q_sqrt @ x)/N) # based on expression 8
t = cp.sqrt(cp.min(x * (Q_sqrt @ x)))     # based on expression 8

objective = cp.Minimize(p - t)            # based on expression 8

constraint_soc1 = [cp.SOC(z[n], (Q_sqrt @ x)[n]) for n in range(N)]
constraint_soc2 = [cp.SOC(cp.quad_over_lin(t, z[n]), x[n]) for n in range(N)]
constraint_soc3 = [cp.SOC(z[n], zero[n]) for n in range(N)]
constraint_soc4 = [cp.SOC(x[n], zero[n]) for n in range(N)]

constraint_other = [cp.sum_squares(Q_sqrt @ x) <= N * (p ** 2),
                    cp.sum(x) == 1, p >= 0, t >= 0]

constraint_all = constraint_other + constraint_soc1 + constraint_soc2 + constraint_soc3 + constraint_soc4

matrix = np.random.random((N, N))
Q_sqrt.value = matrix.T @ matrix # to make positive definite

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraint_all)

prob.solve()
print("status:", prob.status)
print("optimal value", prob.value)
```

Note that I am using `cp.sum_squares(Q_sqrt @ x)` syntax to ensure it is not only DCP-compliant but DPP-compliant as well (refer [Section 4.1](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/diff_cvxpy.pdf)).

Firstly, I noticed my `p = cp.sqrt(cp.sum_squares(Q_sqrt @ x)/N)` part of the objective (first term of *expression 8*) is not DCP and is not sure how to fix it.

Also, I was told that this `x.T @ Q @ x <= N * p**2` constraint was required to be reformulated using `cp.quad_over_lin`, however, as stated I require it to follow DPP rules (for `cvxpylayers`) as well, hence I am unsure how to change `cp.sum_squares(Q_sqrt @ x) <= N * (p ** 2)` to follow `cp.quad_over_lin`.

Lastly, I am sure I have other parts of my code wrongly implemented as well. Any help on this problem is really appreciated!

**EDIT 1**: note that the final solution does not have to call `cvxpylayers`, but just be DPP-compliant so that it can be integrated with `cvxpylayers` after.

**__________________________________________________________________________**

**NEW**

**EDIT 2**: I have now realized that this is probably a multivariate problem, to minimize `p - t` given variables `x,z,p,t`. I don't know why this didn't cross my mind earlier.

Given the snippet problem above, my latest attempt is as follows:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

N = 5

Q_sqrt = cp.Parameter((N, N))
Q = cp.Parameter((N, N))

x = cp.Variable(N)
z = cp.Variable(N)
p = cp.Variable()
t = cp.Variable()

objective = cp.Minimize(p - t)

constraint_soc = [z == Q @ x, x.value * z >= t ** 2, z >= 0, x >= 0]

constraint_other = [cp.quad_over_lin(Q_sqrt @ x, N) <= p ** 2, cp.sum(x) == 1, p >= 0, t >= 0]

constraint_all = constraint_other + constraint_soc

matrix = np.random.random((N, N))
a_matrix = matrix.T @ matrix
Q.value = a_matrix
Q_sqrt.value = np.sqrt(a_matrix)

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraint_all)

prob.solve(verbose=True)
print("status:", prob.status)
print("optimal value", prob.value)
```

However, I am still getting the error:

> DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
> The following constraints are not DCP:
> quad_over_lin(param7788 @ var7790, 5.0) <= power(var7792, 2.0) , because the following subexpressions are not:
> |--  quad_over_lin(param7788 @ var7790, 5.0) <= power(var7792, 2.0)

for this `x.T @ Q @ x <= N * p**2` constraint (my attempt: `cp.quad_over_lin(Q_sqrt @ x, N) <= p ** 2`).

Besides that the problem is also **SOCP** as mentioned above, so my constraints in `constraint_soc` is probably wrong, but I am not sure how to loop/assign variables based on [this](https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/socp.html).

**EDIT 3**: after *ErlingMOSEK*'s suggestion on the constraint, I've changed my constraint from `cp.quad_over_lin(Q_sqrt @ x, N) <= p ** 2` to `cp.quad_over_lin(Q_sqrt @ x, p) <= N * p` and it now runs, however,

A new error appeared

> Solver 'ECOS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.

which I assume is due to the problem being **SOCP** (my second issue) and I am unsure how to construct the SOCP just based on [this](https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/socp.html) example.

**EDIT 4**: using **EDIT 2/3** and Erling's answer along with a different solver as Erling suggested, the problem was solved. Note I used `XPRESS` solver instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change

x.T @ Q @ x <= N * p**2

to

(x.T @ Q @ x)/p <= N * p

assuming p>=0.

Btw if you want to know more about how to formulate this as a SOCP, then consult [the Mosek modelling cookbok](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/index.html).

Comment: hi, as per your advice, by changing my constraint to look like cp.quad_over_lin(Q_sqrt @ x, p) <= N * p works!!, however, I am now getting this error:

Solver 'ECOS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.

which I assume is related to my second issue, which is how do I frame it to be SOCP, and using cp.SOC in my constraint as per the last link's example. I am unsure as the example does not use Variables in the loop.

I really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Why do not you try another optimizer like www.mosek.com.  I think it is fair to say Mosek is more robust than Ecos.

Comment: hmm mosek is paid, I cant afford it sorry

Comment: It is free for academic research though. Good luck anyway.

Comment: I am not completely sure, but I feel my issue is with the way I structure my expression/problem is not right as a SOCP, I cant get it to be in a similar format as this example https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/socp.html

Comment: You could try using the free Mosek trial version. Also please read my revised post. It has reference to our modelling cook that tells you how rewrite the problem. It is unlikely to help since that is what Cvxpy does already for you.

Comment: I will accept this answer as along with your suggestion to the formula change, using a different solver did indeed solve it. Thank you for your patience.