# syntax in defining constraints in CVXPY

Tags: optimization, syntax, cvxpy

I am new to CVXPY, I learn by running examples and I found this post: [How to construct a SOCP problem and solve using cvxpy and cvxpylayers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65227344/how-to-construct-a-socp-problem-and-solve-using-cvxpy-and-cvxpylayers) @ben

[image]

The author provided the codes (Below I've corrected the line that caused an error in OP's EDIT 2):

```py
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

N = 5

Q_sqrt = cp.Parameter((N, N))
Q = cp.Parameter((N, N))

x = cp.Variable(N)
z = cp.Variable(N)
p = cp.Variable()
t = cp.Variable()

objective = cp.Minimize(p - t)

constraint_soc = [z == Q @ x, x.value * z >= t ** 2, z >= 0, x >= 0]  # <-- my question

constraint_other = [cp.quad_over_lin(Q_sqrt @ x, p) <= N * p, cp.sum(x) == 1, p >= 0, t >= 0]

constraint_all = constraint_other + constraint_soc

matrix = np.random.random((N, N))
a_matrix = matrix.T @ matrix
Q.value = a_matrix
Q_sqrt.value = np.sqrt(a_matrix)

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraint_all)

prob.solve(verbose=True)
print("status:", prob.status)
print("optimal value", prob.value)
```

My question is here: `x.value * z >= t ** 2`
why only `x.value` while `z` not?

Actually I tried `x * z`, `x.value * z.value`, they both throw out errors, only the one in the original post works, which is `x.value * z`.

I googled and found this [page](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dcp/index.html) and [this](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html), looks most relevant, but still failed to find an answer.

But both `x` and `z` are variables and defined as such

```py
x = cp.Variable(N)
z = cp.Variable(N)
```

why only `x` needs a `.value` after?? Maybe it's a trivial question to experienced users, but I really don't get it. Thank you.

---

**Update: two follow-up questions**

Thanks to @MichalAdamaszek the first question above is clear: `x.value` didn't make sense here. A suggestion is using `constraint_soc = [z == Q @ x] + [ z[i]>=cp.quad_over_lin(t, x[i]) for i in range(N) ]`

I have two following questions:

1. is it better to write the second of the soc constraint as : `[ x[i]>=cp.quad_over_lin(t, z[i]) for i in range(N) ]`? because in the question we only know that z[i] > 0 for sure. Or it doesn't matter at all in cvxpy? I tired both, both returned a similar optimal value.
2. I noticed that for the two constraints:

`$x^TQx <= Np^2 $` and `$ x_i z_i >= t^2 $`

the quadratic terms were always intentionally split into two linear terms:
`cp.quad_over_lin(Q_sqrt @ x, p) <= N * p` and `z[i]>=cp.quad_over_lin(t, x[i])` respectively.

Is it because that in cvxpy, it is not allowed to have quadratic terms in (in)equality constraints? Is there an documentation to those basic rules?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this code makes much sense. At the point you construct ``constraint_soc`` ``x.value`` is ``None`` and you probably get some ``NaN``s in the data. Also, both ``x`` and ``z`` are N-dimensional, so it is not even clear what you wanted to achieve (mathematically).

Comment: My best guess is that you mean ``constraint_soc = [z == Q @ x] + [ z[i]>=cp.quad_over_lin(t, x[i]) for i in range(N) ]``, but I'm not sure. At least then you get a problem that parses and solves. But it's up to you.

Comment: Hi @MichalAdamaszek thank you for your help. The code is not written by me, it's copied from the linked question. To ease the read, I'll also add the picture of OP's problem in this post. At my end, the script can be run until it says that the solver (mosek) cannot solve it... strange mosek cannot handle it though, it means at least the problem is assembled properly. The only confusing part is the `x.value * z` i totally don't understand why here only this code works, not `z.value`...

Comment: Mosek cannot solve it because you have NaNs in the input coming from the ``None`` value as in my first comment. This is simply wrong to use ``x.value`` at that point, not every code found on the internet is correct. Please try the suggestion from my 2nd comment. It implements the condition ``x[i]*z[i]>=t^2``

Comment: Thank you @MichalAdamaszek for answering it explicitly. Now I see that the reason I didn't get OP's code simply because it was not correct... I tried the line in your second comment, indeed it works! I'll update my question accordingly. There are two details I'd like to hear what you think. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I split the quadratic terms like I did because I like this construction. Under the hood it is completely symmetric and maps to ``(x,z,t) \in RSOC`` where RSOC denotes the rotated quadratic cone, at least when you are using a conic solver. You could also formulate it in other ways that make it clear that x,z play symmetric roles. Note that the cone constraint implies that x,z are nonnegative (it is part of the definition) and you don't have to specify that separately. More information about what goes on underneath in https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html

Comment: The documentation of the basic rules is in https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/functions/index.html#atomic-functions If you are new to Disciplined Convex Programming then I also recommend reading http://ask.cvxr.com/t/why-isnt-cvx-accepting-my-model-read-this-first/570 (it is for CVX, an analogous tool for Matlab). Everything there applies to CVXPY

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thank you so much for the extensive explanation and links to learn. I just installed cvxpy a few days ago, completely new. You helped me a lot in getting it. Thank you!